# Coloring only particular string in datagridview colum in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a function name called highlight that highlights particular cell if it contains a word that I want to highlight. 
My problem is, instead of coloring only the part that string matches, it colors entire string inside the cell.

I have not found a way anywhere on web on coloring particular string inside the cell.
Does anyone know about this ? Below is my function for changing string color for one that contains term

```
private void highLight(string term)
    {

        if (term != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3] == null)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }

                else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(term) || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Contains(term) || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString().Contains(term))
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(term))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }

                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Contains(term))
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString().Contains(term))
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                    string multirow = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: No, It is impossible using default `DataGridView` :( 
Use custom DataGridView to achieve this.

Comment: Look at https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/